# ability to dynamically add and delete rows in a table in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular

I am creating an reactive form in angular 7 with the ability to dynamically add and delete rows in a table.

What I need is

[image]

I need to add the values entered in these controls to the table after the user clicks the Add button.

The table rows should contain these values along with the delete button in the last column.

How do I achieve this using reactive forms.

Currently my UI looks like this

```
 <form [formGroup]="frmFirm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
       <div *ngIf="FirmDetails && FirmDetails.Firm" class="card-body scrollClass" style="width:100%">
        <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Websites</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FirmDetails.Websites}}</div>
                      </div>
             </div>
        </div>
  </form>
```

Component

```
import { Component, Injectable, NgZone, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FirmService } from '../services/firm.service';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { CommonDataService} from '../services/common.data.service';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
    selector: 'mgr-firm',
    templateUrl: './firm.component.html'
})

export class FirmComponent implements OnInit {
    private Error: string;
    public FirmDetails: any;
    public EditMode: boolean;
    public Editor = ClassicEditor;
    public EditorConfig : string;
    public events: string[] = [];
    @Input() FirmId: number;
    DateFoundedDate: Date;
    public frmFirm: FormGroup;

    constructor( private _fb: FormBuilder, private firmService: FirmService, private commonDataService: CommonDataService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getFirmDetails();
        this.initializeFormModel();
    }


    initializeFormModel() {
        this.frmFirm = this._fb.group({
             firmName: [''],
             shortName: [''],
             alternateName: [''],
             dateFounded: [''],
             firmHistory: [''],
             People: [''],

        });
    }

    setFormValues(FirmDetails: any) {
            this.frmFirm.patchValue({
                firmName: FirmDetails.Firm.NAME,
                shortName: FirmDetails.Firm.SHORT_NAME,
                alternateName: FirmDetails.Firm.ALTERNATE_NAME,
                dateFounded: FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED,
                firmHistory: FirmDetails.Firm.HISTORY_HTML,
                People: FirmDetails.People


            });
    }



    getFirmDetails() {
        if (this.FirmId != null) {
        this.firmService.getFirmDetails(this.FirmId)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.FirmDetails = data;
                this.setFormValues(this.FirmDetails);
            },
            err => {
                this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
            },
            () => {
            });
        }
    }

   get  dateFoundedDate(): Date {
         var dateString = this.FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED;
         var seconds = parseInt(dateString.replace(/\/Date\(([0-9]+)[^+]\//i, "$1"));
         var date = new Date(seconds);
         return date;
   }

    saveManager() {
        this.firmService.createFirm(this.FirmDetails)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.getFirmDetails();
                this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
            },
            err => {
                this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
            },
            () => {
            });
    }




    dateFoundedChanged(dateFoundedDate: Date) {
        this.DateFoundedDate = dateFoundedDate;
    }
}
```

updated UI

```
  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Websites</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <!-- <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FirmDetails.Websites[0].WEBSITE_URL}}</div> -->
                        <!-- <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control"
                             /> -->
                             <div formArrayName="websites"
                             *ngFor="let item of frmFirm.get('websites').controls; let i = index; let last = last">
                             <div [formGroupName]="i">
                               <input formControlName="websiteUrl" placeholder="Website Url">
                               <input formControlName="username" placeholder="User Name">
                               <input formControlName="password" placeholder="Password">

                               <button (click)="removeWebsite()">Remove Website</button>
                               <button (click)="addWebsite()" *ngIf="last">Add Website</button>
                             </div>
                           </div>   
                    </div>
                </div>
```

updated component

```
 import { Component, Injectable, NgZone, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FirmService } from '../services/firm.service';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { CommonDataService} from '../services/common.data.service';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, FormArray} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
    selector: 'mgr-firm',
    templateUrl: './firm.component.html'
})

export class FirmComponent implements OnInit {
    private Error: string;
    public FirmDetails: any;
    public EditMode: boolean;
    public Editor = ClassicEditor;
    public EditorConfig : string;
    public events: string[] = [];
    @Input() FirmId: number;
    DateFoundedDate: Date;
    public frmFirm: FormGroup;

    constructor( private _fb: FormBuilder, private firmService: FirmService, private commonDataService: CommonDataService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getFirmDetails();
        this.initializeFormModel();
    }


    initializeFormModel() {
        this.frmFirm = this._fb.group({
             firmName: [''],
             shortName: [''],
             alternateName: [''],
             dateFounded: [''],
             firmHistory: [''],
             People: [''],
             websites: this._fb.array([
                this.createWebsite()
            ])
        });
    }

    // public addWebsite(): void {
    //     const websites = this.frmFirm.get('websites') as FormArray;
    //     websites.push(this._fb.control(''));
    //   }


      public addWebsite(): void {
        this.websites.push(this.createWebsite());
      }

    public removeWebsite(index: number): void {
        const websites = this.frmFirm.get('websites') as FormArray;
        websites.removeAt(index);
      }

      private createWebsite(): FormGroup {
        return this._fb.group({
          websiteUrl: [''],
          username: [''],
          password: ['']
        });
      }


      get websites(): FormArray {
        return <FormArray>this.frmFirm.get('websites');
      }

    setFormValues(FirmDetails: any) {
            this.frmFirm.patchValue({
                firmName: FirmDetails.Firm.NAME,
                shortName: FirmDetails.Firm.SHORT_NAME,
                alternateName: FirmDetails.Firm.ALTERNATE_NAME,
                dateFounded: FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED,
                firmHistory: FirmDetails.Firm.HISTORY_HTML,
                People: FirmDetails.People
            });
            const websiteGroup = this._fb.group({
                  websiteUrl: FirmDetails.Websites[0].WEBSITE_URL,
                  username: FirmDetails.Websites[0].USERNAME,
                  password: FirmDetails.Websites[0].PASSWORD
              });
              this.frmFirm.setControl('websites', this._fb.array([websiteGroup]));
    }



    getFirmDetails() {
        if (this.FirmId != null) {
        this.firmService.getFirmDetails(this.FirmId)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.FirmDetails = data;
                this.setFormValues(this.FirmDetails);
            },
            err => {
                this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
            },
            () => {
            });
        }
    }

   get  dateFoundedDate(): Date {
         var dateString = this.FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED;
         var seconds = parseInt(dateString.replace(/\/Date\(([0-9]+)[^+]\//i, "$1"));
         var date = new Date(seconds);
         return date;
   }

    saveManager() {
        this.firmService.createFirm(this.FirmDetails)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.getFirmDetails();
                this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
            },
            err => {
                this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
            },
            () => {
            });
    }




    dateFoundedChanged(dateFoundedDate: Date) {
        this.DateFoundedDate = dateFoundedDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is `FormArray`.

Angular documentation has it nicely explained with examples that cover your use case of needing to add and remove form group (in your case that would be row with firm details).

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays

Example of what should work in your case.

Template

```
<div formArrayName="companies"
  *ngFor="let item of form.get('companies').controls; let i = index; let last = last">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <input formControlName="firmName" placeholder="Firm name">
    <input formControlName="shortName" placeholder="Short name">
    <input formControlName="alternateName" placeholder="Alternate name">
    <input formControlName="dateFounded" placeholder="Founded">
    <input formControlName="firmHistory" placeholder="History">
    <input formControlName="People" placeholder="People">
    <button (click)="removeCompany()">Remove company</button>
    <button (click)="addCompany()" *ngIf="last">Add company</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component

```
...

public form: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    companies: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createCompany() ])
  });
}

public addCompany(): void {
  const companies = this.form.get('companies') as FormArray;
  companies.push(this.createItem());
}

public removeCompany(index: number): void {
  const companies = this.form.get('companies') as FormArray;
  companies.removeAt(index);
}

private createCompany(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    firmName: [''],
    shortName: [''],
    alternateName: [''],
    dateFounded: [''],
    firmHistory: [''],
    People: [''],
  });
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno I am able to now able to add but not sure how to bind the control the first time the form is loaded. I am adding to the post what I have done so far

Comment: I have updated post by adding additional info i.e updated component and updatedUI. I am currently getting the error Cannot find control with path: 'websites -> 0 -> username'

Comment: If i uncomment these line the errors go but i cant see existing value bound

Comment: Also what i have noticed is the add button disssapears after adding twice. I should be able to add any number of websites. So i presume removing the ngif condition should be fine. does the forloop change as well

Comment: The few issues I see in your updated code are:
* when you are adding new item to array you aren't adding group, but control
  * `websites.push(this._fb.control(''));`
* I'm not 100% sure what you are getting in the response, but what you "patch" needs to match your form model -> remember `websites` is an array and you are adding an object to it so be sure you do that

Comment: Hi Bruno , I have updated the component again. Have changed the add method based on your comments. I found out the reason why the data was not getting bound to the UI elements while debugging. Websites under FirmDetails model is array of objects. At the moment for testing i have added websiteUrl: FirmDetails.Websites[0].WEBSITE_URL. What if i have more than one object. How do I bind then

Answer (score 2):

I have something similar, but I add them as "blocks" instead of "rows". Click the "Add Another Address" button to add another block.

I'm sure the formatting is just a matter of a few modifications to the layout.

[image]

The more challenging part is the code. To have repeatable sets of fields, you need to use a FormArray where each element is its own FormGroup.

I have a complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-ReactiveForms/tree/master/Demo-Final

Well, the prior answer beat me to it ... but I'm leaving this as well as the link provides a complete working example.

Comment: Thanks Deborah . I shall have a look at your working solution as I am facing some issues which I have mentioned under Bruno’s reply. I wasn’t seeing the button to download or git clone

Comment: I hope your solution covers the answers to my question

Comment: You need to go up in the tree to git clone: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-ReactiveForms